# Python regular expression to match IPV4 address doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the `re` library.

```
def validate_ip(self, ip):
    pattern = re.compile(r'([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|2[5][0-5])\.{4}')
    matchObj = re.match(pattern, ip)

    if matchObj == None:
        print "Invalid IP:", ip
        sys.exit(0)
```

When I pass the IP **192.0.0.0**, the output is:

```
Invalid IP: 192.0.0.0
```

Why is it not matching?

Comment: Why use a regex for this? Python comes with [batteries](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ipaddress.html) included.

Comment: @Tichodroma: from Python 3.3 onwards only, though. The OP is using Python 2, by the looks of it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, `print` is a sign for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pattern matches one 3-digit number, followed by exactly 4 dots:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|2[5][0-5])\.{4}')
>>> pattern.match('255....')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1026eda80>
```

The `{4}` doesn't apply to everything preceding it; it only applies to *just* the `\.`.

You want this instead:

```
r'(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|2[5][0-5])\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|2[5][0-5])'
```

This matches your number pattern plus a `.` dot *3* times, because now the `{3}` applies to everything in the preceding grouped expression (using `(...)`). You then still need to match the last digit group separately.

Demo:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|2[5][0-5])\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|2[5][0-5])')
>>> pattern.match('192.0.0.0')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1023bf588>
```

As an aside, just use `if not match:` to test for a match failure; `None` is a false value in a boolean context. Even if you really wanted to test for `None`, you should be using `if match is None:`, using an identity test.

Comment: Just for the record, this expression doesn't match all valid IPv4 addresses.  It misses e.g. `192.168.0.01` or `192.168.1`, which are both valid synonyms for `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: `192.168.0.01` would actually match. The `[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]` part allows for up to two leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Python 3.3+, use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ipaddress.html) library.

```
import ipaddress

for ip in ["192.0.0.0", "0.0.0.0", "192.168.0.256"]:
    try:
        ipaddress.ip_address(ip)
        print("{} is valid".format(ip));
    except ValueError:
        print("{} is invalid".format(ip))
```

Output:

```
192.0.0.0 is valid
0.0.0.0 is valid
192.168.0.256 is invalid
```

Comment: `ipaddress` is new in Python 3.3; the OP is using Python 2 judging by the `print` statement.